# How can I show that an element does not belong to a certain ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let
$$
R = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots]}{(x_1 - x_2^2, x_2 - x_3^2, \cdots)}.
$$
I'm trying to show that $R$ does not satisfy the ascending chain condition for principal ideals, though I'm not entirely sure that it doesn't. So far, I've come up with letting $ f_n(x) = x_n - x_{n+1}$. Then we have
\begin{align}
f_{n}(x) &= x_n - x_{n+1} \\
         &= x_{n+1}^2 - x_{n+2}^2 \\
         &= (x_{n+1} + x_{n+2}) (x_{n+1} - x_{n+2}).
\end{align}
That is, $ (f_n) \subseteq (f_{n+1})$. Then we have the chain $ (f_1) \subseteq (f_2) \subseteq (f_3) \subseteq \cdots$. If I can show that $ (f_n) \neq (f_{n+1}) $ then it becomes clear that the ascending chain does not stabilize. I think the most logical way to approach this is to show that $ f_{n+1} \notin (f_n) $. Here's where I'm having trouble, I have no clue how to show that an element *doesn't* belong to an ideal.

Comment: It might be easier to just use $f_n=x_n$. Do you see why this chain doesn't stabilize?

Comment: @KReiser Alright, I can see why $x_n$ is a simpler principal ideal. The relation in the ideal gives $x_n = x_{n+1}^2$ so $(x_n) \subseteq (x_{n+1})$. Now to show the inclusion is strict, suppose that $x_{n+1} \in (x_n)$. That is, there is a polynomial $p \in R$ such that $p \cdot x_n = x_{n+1}$. I'm still running into trouble here. I tried rewriting this as $p \cdot x_{n+1}^2 = x_{n+1} \Longrightarrow x_{n+1} (p \cdot x_{n+1} - 1) = 0$ but without knowing if $R$ is an integral domain, this seems unfruitful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, we've shifted to considering $f_n=x_n$ and identified that if $x_{n+1}\in (x_n)$, then $x_{n+1}(p\cdot x_{n+1}-1)=0$, so it's enough to show that $R$ is a domain.

Let $a,b\in R$ be nonzero, and our goal is to show that $ab\neq 0$. Pick some $n\gg0$ so that $a=p(x_n)$ and $b=q(x_n)$ for polynomials $p,q$, where we know by the assumption $a,b\neq 0$ that $p,q\neq 0$. Then $ab=p(x_n)q(x_n)\neq 0$ since $\Bbb Z[x_n]\cap (x_1-x_2^2,\cdots)=0$ inside $\Bbb Z[x_1,\cdots]$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm seeing it now. Just to clarify any loose ends, we're allowed to assume that $a$ and $b$ are polynomials in only one variable because of the relations in the ideal, correct? Specifically, given an arbitrary polynomial in $n$ variables, we can just choose the greatest index and rewrite the other variables in terms of that using the fact that $x_i = x_{i+1}^2$. Then each polynomial is merely an element in $\mathbb{Z}[x_n]$ which is an integral domain. As a consequence, doesn't that also mean the ideal is prime?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. It's important that $\Bbb Z[x_n]$ does not intersect our ideal inside $\Bbb Z[x_1,\cdots]$, which we can see by unique factorization.